# ReactJS: Mapped data not showing in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I have a function `previewData()` which I use to map an array of data as follows (inside the render method):

```
const {formData} = this.state;

function previewData() {

    formData.map((item, key) => {
        console.log("item", item.question);
        return (<div>{item.question}</div>)
    })
}
```

Inside the `return` statement of the render method I'm using that function like this:

```
<div className="form_preview polaroid unchange_div">
    {previewData()}
</div>
```

This is how I'm pushing data into my array (outside the render method):

```
addFormData() {

    const {formQuestion} = this.props;

    const formRawData = {
      'question': formQuestion,
      'type': this.state.qtype
    }

    this.state.formData.push(formRawData);

    this.setState({
      success: true
    })
  }
```

I can see my console also logs correctly, but the values are not populated in my view. What seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `previewData()` returns the mapped result so that your array of mapped `<div>` elements can be rendered inside of the `polaroid` container:

```
function previewData() {

     /* Add return before formData.map */
      return formData.map((item, key) => {
        console.log("item", item.question);
        return (
          <div>{item.question}</div>
        )
      })
    }
```

Comment: I thought just returning inside the mapping function was enough. Anyway thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hey, Im a bit new to this and wanted to try this solution out. But could you explain what the "key" is? Where do you get it? Im unsure how to implement it into my code. Thanks!

Comment: @webdesignnoob - sure :) `key` is actual the numerical index of `item` in the `formData` array. It's passed from the `map( .. )` function as a second argument to the callback function that you provide (ie, where the `<div>` is returned). Here's a bit more info on the parameters passed from `map( .. )` to your callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters - hope that helps!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much for your help! :)